# Logstash escape JSON Keys

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have multiple systems that send data as JSON Request Body. This is my simple config file.

```
input {
  http {
    port => 5001
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
  }  
}
```

In most cases this works just fine. I can look at the json data with kibana.
In some cases the JSON will not be processed. It hase something to do with the JSON escaping. For example: If a key contains a '.', the JSON will not be processed.

I can not control the JSON. Is there a way to escape these characters in a JSON key?

Update: As mentioned in the comments I'll give an example of a JSON String (Content is altered. But I,ve tested the JSON String. It has the same behavior as the original.):

```
{
  "http://example.com": {
    "a": "",
    "b": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should show a sample JSON you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My research brings me back to my post, finally.

Before Elasticsearch 2.0 dots in the key were allowed. Since version 2.0 this is not the case anymore. 
One user in the logstash forum developed a ruby script that takes care of the dots in json keys:

```
filter {
  ruby {
    init => "
        def remove_dots hash
            new = Hash.new
            hash.each { |k,v|
                if v.is_a? Hash
                    v = remove_dots(v)
                end
                new[ k.gsub('.','_') ] = v
                if v.is_a? Array
                    v.each { |elem|
                        if elem.is_a? Hash
                            elem = remove_dots(elem)
                        end
                        new[ k.gsub('.','_') ] = elem
                    } unless v.nil?
                end
            } unless hash.nil?
            return new
        end
    "
    code => "
        event.instance_variable_set(:@data,remove_dots(event.to_hash))
    "
  }
}
```

All credits go to @hanzmeier1234 ([Field name cannot contain ‘.’](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/field-name-cannot-contain/33251/39))